# React-native - TextInput decimal-pad showing comma instead of a dot on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

Some iOS devices seems to be showing a `,` (comma) instead of a `.` on the decimal-pad. I believe this is to do with the keyboard language / locale. Is there a way I can force the `decimal-pad` to show a `.` regardless of keyboard language / locale?

```
<TextInput
    rejectResponderTermination={false}
    style={[
        {
            fontSize: entryValueFontSize,
            height: height,
        },
        calculatorStyles.inputsShared,
        calculatorStyles.amountInput,
        theme.inputsShared,
    ]}
    autoCapitalize={'none'}
    placeholder={entryValueLabel}
    placeholderTextColor={theme.placeholderTextColor}
    keyboardType={'decimal-pad'}
    returnKeyType={'done'}
    defaultValue={''}
    value={isNaN(this.state.entryValue) ? '' : this.state.entryValue}
    onChangeText={(entryValue) => {
        this.onEntryValueChange(entryValue);
    }}
/>
```

Problem:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It is not possible to force keyboard to use comma. It is based on Region for example Czechia has comma. The solution I have created is to replace comma for decimal with point once comma is entered

```js
<TextInput
  onChangeText={(entryValue) => {
    // I am passing keyboardType as prop
    if (keyboardType === 'decimal-pad') {
      this.onEntryValueChange(entryValue.replace(',', '.'));
    } else {
      this.onEntryValueChange(entryValue);
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Ye that's what I'm doing but this is annoying when working with numbers. I'm going to end up implementing a visual keyboard.

Comment: IMO- this happens because the phone is set to an EU location. where people use (comma) instead of (dot) ex: 1.234,56 (EU style) while rest use 1,234.56

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth there is not reason to guess. You can easily find this information where a comma "," or dot "." is used as decimal separator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Usage_worldwide